# What's json syntax for {"data":"w-file1","attr":{"rel":"file"}} in php?

Tags: php, json

What would be php code to get this json?

```
{  "data": "w-file1",
   "attr": { "rel" : "file"}
}
```

I am getting `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW` error for

```
$file = ("data" => "w-file1","attr" => ("rel" => "file"));
echo json_encode($file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$file needs to be an array as does the `attr` key:

```
$file = array("data" => "w-file1","attr" => array("rel" => "file"));
echo json_encode($file);
```

Of course, you could inline it:

```
echo json_encode(array("data" => "w-file1","attr" => array("rel" => "file")));
```

Or, there is the OOP approach:

```
$file = new stdClass();
$file->data = 'w-file';
$file->attr = new stdClass();
$file->attr->rel = "file";
echo json_encode($file);
```

Comment: @cwallenpoole: How can I debug what's inside `$file` before I jsno_encode it?

Comment: `print_r($file, TRUE)` returns a string of the contents of an object.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Any chance to answer this one too? Please :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137010/how-to-correctly-retun-an-array-to-ajax-call-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `array` for $file and attr:

```
$file = array("data" => "w-file1","attr" => array("rel" => "file"));
echo json_encode($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = array(
    "data" => "w-file1",
    "attr" => array("rel" => "file")
);
echo json_encode($file);
```