# How to correctly return an array to ajax call in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

ajax calls below php and expect an array of json to be return. I think I have the data ready but don't know how to return them correctly.

```
$files = array();
foreach($db2_databaselist as $db) {

    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->data = date('Y-m-d--H:i:s',strtotime($db));
    $file->attr = new stdClass();
    $file->attr->rel = "file";
    $file->attr->timestamp = $db.$type[0];

    $files[] = json_encode($file);
}
   echo "<pre>Output = " . print_r($files,TRUE) . "</pre>";
   echo "<BR><BR><BR>";
   print_r($files, TRUE);
```

where `print_r($files,TRUE)` gives me

```
Output = Array
(
    [0] => {"data":"2011-08-07--02:30:05","attr":{"rel":"file","timestamp":"20110807023005w"}}
    [1] => {"data":"2011-07-31--02:30:09","attr":{"rel":"file","timestamp":"20110731023009w"}}
    [2] => {"data":"2011-07-24--02:30:09","attr":{"rel":"file","timestamp":"20110724023009w"}}
)
```

But `print_r($files,TRUE)` returns nothing.

How can I get php to return

```
[
 {"data":"2011-08-07--02:30:05","attr":{"rel":"file","timestamp":"20110807023005w"}},
 {"data":"2011-07-31--02:30:09","attr":{"rel":"file","timestamp":"20110731023009w"}},
    [2] => {"data":"2011-07-24--02:30:09","attr":{"rel":"file","timestamp":"20110724023009w"}}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need json encode after the loop as things are.** You need **[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**. Your array values are already JSON strings, which means that using json_encode will only escape the strings!

Instead:

```
echo '['.implode(',',$files).']';
```

OR! You could skip json_encode on this line:

```
$files[] = json_encode($file);
```

And the end of the loop would look like this instead:

```
    $files[] = $file;
}

$files = json_encode( $files );
```

Comment: I like the second solution better. Great that you spotted it.

Comment: @Radek I didn't see the json_encode in the look first go round

Comment: I did it this way because I didn't know how to make `$files` an object so I can use objects only. So I made `$files` an array. Wors very smoothly now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `json_encode` php function

```
print json_encode($files);
```

Answer (score -1):

`echo json_encode($files)` should be enough